# PHP Exclude Dups Merging Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I would like to merge two multidimension arrays. Consider the scenario below. I have two arrays I would like to merge. I would however like to remove / avoid merging any duplicate records that can be identified as they share the 'documentId'.

Array #1

```
Array 
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            ['documentId'] => 124   
            ['name'] => "Title #1"
            ['version'] => "1"
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            ['documentId'] => 123   
            ['name'] => "Title #2"
            ['version'] => "1"
        )
)
```

Array #2

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            ['documentId'] => 123   
            ['name'] => "Title #2 updated"
            ['version'] => "2"
        )
)
```

New Array/ Merged Array

```
Array

    Array 
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                ['documentId'] => 123   
                ['name'] => "Title #2 updated"
                ['version'] => "2"
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                ['documentId'] => 124   
                ['name'] => "Title #2"
                ['version'] => "1"
            )
    )
```

I have looked at the array_replace_recursive() function. I am not able to use it as it needs to specifically compare on attribute 'documentId' rather than the key of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the arrays and set them into another array with the document id as the key. Later values with overwrite the previous values already set.

Example:

```
$merged = array();
foreach($array1 as $value){
    $merged[$value['documentId']] = $value;
}

foreach($array2 as $value){
    $merged[$value['documentId']] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Set the documentId as a key when merging $arr1 and $arr2

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ( $arr1 as $v ) {
    $new_array[ $v['documentID'] ] = $v;
}
foreach ( $arr2 as $v ) {
    $new_array[ $v['documentID'] ] = $v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_column()` can re-index using the `documentID` so that `array_replace()` will replace elements of `$array1` that have identical keys in `$array2`:

```
$result = array_replace(array_column($array1, null, 'documentId'),
                        array_column($array2, null, 'documentId'));
```

Then if needed to re-index:

```
$result = array_values($result)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this won't work. array_merge will re-index numeric keys and the `documentId` value is numeric. http://codepad.viper-7.com/kwCJZr. You could likely use a union with (shorthand) `a_c($2...) + a_c($1...)`. Pretty snazzy though. I haven't worked with array_column at all (stuck on 5.4).

Comment: Thanks, yes.  Edited with `array_replace()` which is what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Loop by two arrays, if you want, you can merge or replace values

```
<?php

$students1 = array(
    0 => array(
        'student_id' => 1,
        'name' => 'John',
        'enrollment' => 'AAA111'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'student_id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Mike',
        'enrollment' => 'BBB222'
    )
);

$students2 = array(
    0 => array(
        'student_id' => 1,
        'name' => 'John',
        'enrollment' => 'AAA111'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'student_id' => 3,
        'name' => 'Anton',
        'enrollment' => 'BBB333'
    )
);

$students = [];

foreach ($students1 as $student) {
    $students[$student['student_id']] = $student;
}

foreach ($students2 as $student) {
    if (!isset($students[$student['student_id']])) {
        $students[$student['student_id']] = $student;
    }
}


var_dump(array_values($students));
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it!